# Using merge in python snowflake connector with pandas dataframe as a source

Tags: python, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm retrieving data from an API and converting the data into a pandas dataframe. I'm using python-snowflake connector to send this data into my snowflake schema as a table.

I want to use merge instead of sending the duplicate data into my snowflake table.

Sample data I'm retrieving from API:

```
|------------|-------------|------------|
|  log_in_ID |   user_id   |   date     |
|------------|-------------|------------|
|    1       |     21      | 02/21/2021 |
|    2       |     22      | 02/24/2021 |
|    3       |     23      | 02/27/2021 |
|    4       |     21      | 02/29/2021 |
|------------|-------------|------------|
```

The log_in_ID is unique

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL(
                 account='my_snowflake_account',
                 user='user',
                 password='password',
                 database='my_database'
                 schema='my_schema',
                 warehouse='warehouse',
                 role='ADMIN'))

pandas_df = 'Some code to get API data and convert into pandas dataframe'

def send_to_snowflake(pandas_df, target_table):
    connect = engine.connect()
    data.tosql(target_table, con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
    connection.close()
    engine.dispose()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   send_to_snowflake(pandas_df, target_table)
```

How can I use merge statement with log_in_id as unique key?

How can I use a pandas dataframe inside the merge query in snowflake-python?

```
merge into target_table using {pandas_dataframe}
      on target_table.log_in_id = {pandas_dataframe}.log_in_id
      when matched then
           update set target_table.user_id = {pandas_dataframe}.user_id and
                  set target_table.date = {pandas_dataframe}.date
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If structure of your API is similar to below format:
[(1, 21, 'A'), (2, 22, 'AA'), (3, 23, 'AB'), (4, 21, 'AC')]

This code will works to merge the API data into snowflake target table without loading source data into tables:

```
import requests
import json
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL


def sample_func():
    engine = create_engine(URL(
                     account='xxx',
                     user='xxx',
                     password='xxx',
                     database='xxx',
                     schema='PUBLIC',
                     warehouse='COMPUTE_WH',
                     role='xxx',
    ))

    connection = engine.connect()
    pandas_df = 'select * from A'

    try:
        cursor_return = connection.execute(pandas_df)
        cursor_result = cursor_return.fetchall()
        api_data = str(cursor_result)[1:-1]
        print(api_data)
        merge_temp = """
        merge into B target_table using (select COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 from values{0}) src
      on target_table.log_in_id = src.COLUMN1
      when matched then
           update set target_table.log_in_id = src.COLUMN1,
                      target_table.user_id = src.COLUMN2,
                      target_table.test_data = src.COLUMN3
      when not matched then
      insert
      (log_in_id, user_id, test_data) values(src.COLUMN1, src.COLUMN2, src.COLUMN3)
        """.format(str(api_data))
        print(merge_temp)
        c_return = connection.execute(merge_temp)
        c_result = c_return.fetchall()
        print(c_result)

        print("Number rows inserted: {0} || Number of rows updated: {1}".format(str(c_result[0][0]), str(c_result[0][1])))
    finally:
        connection.close()
        engine.dispose()

sample_func()
```

But I would recommend to load your API data into temp table and use merge statement on temp table, this approach will more faster then loading it from dataframe or csv files.

Comment: Does this work if the structure of the API is [{'id': '1', 'name': 'a'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'b'}] ?

Comment: Need small change in the code

Comment: api_data = [tuple(i.values())for i in d] where d is your input data variable name

Comment: I have used this solution as a sample to understand the problem similar to which I have worked.